# Incremental library download on Google Music Manager

Tags: macos, windows-8.1, download, google-music

I am trying to download my library to my mac or Windows 8 machine but everytime I click on "Download my library" it runs through and always errors on a few songs (never the same ones).

When I click on "Download my library" again when it completed it then proceeds to download the whole catalog again, rather than the ones that are missing!

How can I just get it to download the ones that its missed - that way when I buy a new album, I don't have to download the whole catalog.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the songs a limited number of times through the Google Play website (https://play.google.com/music/). Afterwards, it will be limited to the Music Manager client.

Click on the 3 dots in the upper right corner of the album cover art, and select download album. It will prompt before you download.

Comment: Thanks I did know about this but was hoping to avoid it due to the silly limit.

Comment: @Cheetah Don't blame Google, blame the music industry. Ultimately, the copyright holders have the final say on how you can download the content you purchased, so even Google can't force artists and record labels to allow unlimited downloads of individual songs and albums. Google did its best to negotiate the best terms for end users, and the major record labels probably rejected any agreement which allows less restricted downloads.